# checkIfValid() on a null object reference (Realm 3.1.3)

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm 3.1.3 and Realm Adapters 2.0 in my project and getting this error when I try to update the adapter using

```
adapter.updateData(RealmManager.stationsDetailsDAO().loadSearch(newText.toLowerCase(), selectedLanguage, type));
```

Here's the error thrown

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid()' on a null object reference
```

when trying to query from the Database

Here's my code :

```
public RealmList<Station> loadSearch(String query, String language, String type) {

    RealmList<Station> stationRealmList = new RealmList<>();

    mRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> mRealm.copyToRealm(stationRealmList)); 
    // To make it a Managed Object

    switch (type) {
        case "Language": {
            RealmQuery<Station> stationRealmQuery = mRealm.where(Station.class);
            stationRealmQuery.equalTo("language", language);
            RealmResults<Station> realmResults = stationRealmQuery.findAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < realmResults.size(); i++) {
                if (realmResults.get(i).getName().contains(query)) {
                    stationRealmList.add(realmResults.get(i));
                }

            }

            return stationRealmList;
        }
        case "Recent":
            HeaderSectionModel realmList = RealmManager.stationsDetailsDAO().loadHeaderData();
            for (int i = 0; i < realmList.getLanguageModelArrayList().size(); i++) {
                if (realmList.getLanguageModelArrayList().get(i).getName().contains(query)) {
                    stationRealmList.add(realmList.getLanguageModelArrayList().get(i));
                }
            }

            return stationRealmList;
        case "Genre": {
            RealmQuery<Station> stationRealmQuery = mRealm.where(Station.class);
            stationRealmQuery.equalTo("genreName", language);
            RealmResults<Station> realmResults = stationRealmQuery.findAll();


            for (int i = 0; i < realmResults.size(); i++) {
                if (realmResults.get(i).getName().contains(query)) {
                    stationRealmList.add(realmResults.get(i));
                }
            }

            return stationRealmList;
        }
    }


    return stationRealmList;
}
```

Comment: because `RealmList<Station> stationRealmList = new RealmList<>();` is not a managed view of a link (as in not obtained from a managed RealmObject with `getRealmListField()`), so `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` doesn't work with it.

Comment: Oh, then how do I make it a managed object?

Comment: What's the workaround here?

Comment: Tried using     mRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> mRealm.copyToRealm(stationRealmList)); 
 but still the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `RealmList<Station> stationRealmList = new RealmList<>();` is not a managed view of a link (as in not obtained **from a managed RealmObject with `getRealmListField()`**), so `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` *doesn't* work with it.

---

The solution is that you're supposed to display a `RealmResults` defined by a `RealmQuery` instead of manually trying to do a contains operation.

```
public RealmResults<Station> loadSearch(String query, String language, String type) { 
    RealmQuery<Station> stationRealmQuery = mRealm.where(Station.class);
    if(query != null && !"".equals(query)) {
        stationRealmQuery.contains("name", query);
    }
    switch (type) {
        case "Language": 
            stationRealmQuery.equalTo("language", language);
            break;
        case "Recent":
            // TODO do something about this one
            break;
        case "Genre": 
            stationRealmQuery.equalTo("genreName", language);
            break;
    }
    return stationRealmQuery.findAll();
}
```

---

If this is not possible, then use a regular `RecyclerView.Adapter` and your own `RealmChangeListener`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense now! Will try it out